# How solve the following system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

The question goes as the following 
$$x-3y+6z=21$$
$$3x+2y-5z=-30$$
$$2x-5y+2z=-6$$

for this one I am really confused and don't even know how to solve it.

I tried to do the elimination method but i came with fractions.

I woud show the process but I'm currently using my phone.

Comment: do you know the Gauss-method?

Comment: What's the problem with fractions?

Comment: No I don't know what that means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left\{\begin{array}{lcr}(A)\;\phantom{1}x-3y+6z&=&21\\
(B)\;3x+2y-5z&=&-30\\
(C)\;2x-5y+2z&=&-6\end{array}\right.$$
is equivalent (through $(B)\mapsto(B-3A)$ and $(C)\mapsto (C-2A)$) to$$\left\{\begin{array}{lcr}(A)\;\phantom{1}x-3y+6z&=&21\\
(B)\;\phantom{3x+}11y-23z&=&-93\\
(C)\;\phantom{2x-\,\,\,}y-10z&=&-48\end{array}\right.$$
that is equivalent (through $(B)\mapsto(B-11C)$) to
$$\left\{\begin{array}{lcr}(A)\;\phantom{1}x-3y+6z&=&21\\
(B)\;\phantom{3x+11y-}87z&=&435\\
(C)\;\phantom{2x-\,\,\,}y-10z&=&-48\end{array}\right.$$
Now use $(B)$ to find the value of $z$, plug it into $(C)$ to find the value of $y$, plug them both into $(A)$ to find the value of $x$. This is known as the [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) method. A good alternative for $3\times 3$ systems is [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule). They both lead to:
$$ (x,y,z)=\color{red}{(-3,2,5)} $$

Comment: Thank you very much, This helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

multiplying the first equation by -3 and adding to the seconde one we get
$$11y-23z=-93$$ (I)
multiplying the first by -2 and adding to the third we get
$$y-10z=-48$$ (II)
can you proceed?
multiplying (II) by -11 and adding this to (I) we obtain
$$87z=435$$ thus $$z=5$$

Answer (score 0):

You can row reduce the matrix with no fractions to

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
 1&0&0&-3\\
 0&1&0&2\\
 0&0&1&5\\
\end{array}\right]$$

giving $x=-3, y=2,z=5$